# How can I wrap the output by double quotes in insert overwrite statements in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

This is my insert overwrite statement:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY /myworkspace/output/f_name/20150714
select concat_ws('|',
coalesce(A,''),
coalesce(B,''),
coalesce(C,''),
coalesce(D,'')
)
FROM TABLE_A;
```

I am getting the output as:

> a|b|c|d

But I want the output as:

> "a"|"b"|"c"|"d"

I am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your table definition should define the format you want the data output to be in. This would insulate you from doing a lot of the concat.

In this case i would define a table which would use Column delimiter as "|" & FIELDS TERMINATED BY '"'

Refer following link : [Create Table Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable)

Answer (score 0):

> `concat_ws` which can be used to specify the delimeter between, but here
>   you wanted to enclose the fields with double quotes ", So use `concat`
>   instead like this

```
select 
concat('"',coalesce(A,''),'"|"',coalesce(B,''),'"|"',coalesce(C,''),'"|"',coalesce(D,''),'"')
from table_a
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation using nested concats:

```
concat('"',
concat_ws('"|"',coalesce(A,''),coalesce(B,''),coalesce(C,''),coalesce(D,''))
,'"')
```

And another using a regexp_replace():

```
regexp_replace(
concat_ws('"|"',coalesce(A,''),coalesce(B,''),coalesce(C,''),coalesce(D,''))
,'(.+)','"$1"')
```